# Apache causing redirection failure with slim framework

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, slim

I got a simple test redirect in the index.php of the slim framework:

```
$app->get('/bob', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response->withRedirect('user/register');
});
```

and the route:

```
$app->get('/user/register', \UserController::class . ':displayProfile')->setName('userRegister');
```

So when going to localhost:3000/bob it should redirect to url localhost:3000/user/register and change the content appropriately. It's not the case and all I get is a white empty page.

At first I thought it was a problem with slim framework. But trying with a different apache server (the one coming with php) I didn't have the problem anymore. The problem happened with the MAMP pro apache server only.

Here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Do you have a clue what setting could cause the redirect to not function ?

(I deleted my other mislead post about this issue)

Comment: Look at your error logs.

Comment: It's hard to detect problem from what you've posted, look at error log, as suggested by @MikaTuupola. But what I can see is that you do `$response->withRedirect('user/register')`, while you should `$response->withRedirect('/user/register')` - note the slash in the beginning.